# For each cell in given range, test if contains search string and return substring removing the search string

Tags: search, replace, foreach, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google spreadsheet with values which are labeled within the cell, but not consistent from column to column.

I need to search a range (specifically current row) of cells to find one which contains a keyword and get the value which follows the keyword.

Example Data:

> Param,Param2,Param3
>   foo:1,bah:31,height:6
>   *price:9*,help:62,
>   height:9,slot:4,*price:6*

Example result:

> Param,Param2,Param3,**price**
>   foo:1,bah:31,height:6,
>  *price:9*,help:62,,**9**
>   height:9,slot:4,*price:6*,**6**

```
function extractValueFromRange(MatchString,myRange) {
  // Get the cells in range to be tested 
  var elements = myRange.

  // Loop through the cells
  // Prefer to use foreach... if possible 
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {

    // Get cell string to be tested
    var element = elements[i-1];

    // Test if the MatchString is found
    if(element.indexOf(SearcchString)>-1){

      // Take out the MatchString
      var myResult = SUBSTITUTE(element,MatchString,"",1);
      // Return the result
      return myResult;
    }

    // if no match found return nothing
    return null; 
  }
```

Comment: The main sheet I want to use this on has columns range(A:EJ)  which is why I am looking to use script rather than in sheet function.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can manage that by formula directly in the spreadsheet.

Below how to extract value after ":" but before ","

Text                      |Result   |  Formula

Param,Param2,Param3,price | #REF!   | =index(split(REGEXEXTRACT(A2;"price:[0-9]*");":");2)

foo:1,bah:31,height:6     | #REF!   | =index(split(REGEXEXTRACT(A3;"price:[0-9]*");":");2)

price:93,help:62,         | 93      | =index(split(REGEXEXTRACT(A4;"price:[0-9]*");":");2)

height:9,slot:4,price:6   | 6       | =index(split(REGEXEXTRACT(A5;"price:[0-9]*");":");2)

Comment: That is helpful to know, but I have to use on wider ranges... eg G1:EJ1
I don't want to concatenate that many cells

Answer (score 0):

=REGEXEXTRACT(join(";",A1:EJ1),"price:(\d+);")

You can join all the values with a delimited or your choice, im using a semicolon in the example.

The regex itself is extracting only the value between the word price, and the semicolon, and specifying that it can be a number of 1 or more characters, any length.